# Standalone program for managing encrypted partitions? Or, How can I manage encrypted partitions in recovery mode?

Tags: recovery-mode, encryption

Android uses dm-crypt for providing disk-encryption as stated in the [implementation notes](https://source.android.com/tech/encryption/android_crypto_implementation.html). Those notes also state (emphasis mine):

> While the actual encryption work is a standard linux kernel feature,
>   enabling it on an Android device proved somewhat tricky. The **Android
>   system tries to avoid incorporating GPL components, so using the
>   cryptsetup command or libdevmapper were not available options**. So
>   making the appropriate ioctl(2) calls into the kernel was the best
>   choice. The Android volume daemon (vold) already did this to support
>   moving apps to the SD card, so I chose to leverage that work for whole
>   disk encryption. The actual encryption used for the filesystem for
>   first release is 128 AES with CBC and ESSIV:SHA256. The master key is
>   encrypted with 128 bit AES via calls to the openssl library.
>
> Once it was decided to put the smarts in vold, it became obvious that
>   invoking the encryption features would be done like invoking other
>   vold commands, by adding a new module to vold (called cryptfs) and
>   teaching it various commands. The commands are checkpw, restart,
>   enablecrypto, changepw and cryptocomplete. They will be described in
>   more detail below.

So Android does not an existing tool due to licensing issues... As a user in recovery mode, I do not have `vold` running and would like to have a minimum program that can:

1. Create a new encrypted partition.
2. Unlock existing encrypted partitions.
3. (optional) View information about the encrypted partition.

Does such a program exist? Ideally it can also run in a non-Android environment, but at the moment it is important to create an encrypted partition in recovery mode.

The subject OS is Android 4.2.2 with CWM 6.0.3.2 as recovery image.